# Bootstrap 3 Displays Content Outside col-md-6 in Django Template

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

Sorry this question is unavoidably kind of long.

I have `basetemplate.html` which other files extend.

**basetemplate.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>....</head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">...</nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">                   
                <div class="col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                {% block profile %}
                    <p>User details here...</p>
                {% endblock %}
                </div>

                <div class = "col-md-6">
                {% block mainBody %}            
                {% endblock %}
                </div>

                <div class = "col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                {% block others %}  
                    <p>Others here...</p>
                {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I now have `home.html` extending `basetemplate.html`:

**home.html**:

```
{% extends "mysite/base.html" %}
{% block mainBody %}
    {% include 'mysite/mainbody.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

And `mainbody.html` contains:

```
{% for article in articles reversed %}      
    <div class="article-wrapper">
        <div class="article-content">
            <p>{{ article.content }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This works well for `home.html`. All my articles are displayed within `<div class = "col-md-6"></div>` but it doesn't for `hashtags.html` page. If I have, say 10 articles coming for a particular *hashtag*, it will display two or more within `<div class = "col-md-6"></div>` and may be three outside it and the rest outside `<div class = "row"></div>`. And sometimes some are even displayed outside `<div class = "container"></div>`.

**hashtag.html**:

```
{% extends "mysite/base.html" %}
{% block mainBody %}
    {% include 'mysite/mainbody.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Query that fetches article for *home.html* is `articles = Article.objects.all()[:10]` while that of *hashtag.html* is `articles = Article.objects.filter(content__icontains=hashtaggedword)[:10]`.

I have checked and checked to see if have any unclosed tag but couldn't find any even after using [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). I have also checked to see if there is something strange with those that display outside `col-md-6` but they are okay and displayed in order of time they are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `article.content` have html tags. Escape them by [escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#escape).

```
{{ article.content|escape }}
```

Comment: Wow! This did it! I indeed have some html tags in `{{ article.content|escape }}`, they are all anchor tags and I do `truncatechars|1000` on each of them. So if I have </a> truncated out it causes those wahala. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

try using this way:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    {% for article in articles reversed %}
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ article.content }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Result of this code is a simple list and you can put this to your column without any problem